# Is there a way in Markdown for creating aliases for HTML symbols or LaTeX commands?

Tags: html, latex, markdown, alias, symbols

Is it possible to create an alias in Markdown in such a way that I could write `-->` and it would display → as it it was written `&#9687;` for HTML right arrow or `$\rightarrow$` for LaTeX right arrow?
Thanks!

I am using Markdown in Jupyter notebook, although it does not implement nice features like the GitHub Flavored Markdown.

Comment: Short answer: no, but you can preprocess the Markdown document (although I’m not aware of a way to hook into the RMarkdown/Knitr/Jupyter process, so doing this well is not trivial). The best you can hope for is inline R code, such as ``r`rarrow` ``, with an appropriate definition of the `rarrow` variable somewhere in the document.

Comment: Hum I see... And is it possible to create some sort of extension for the Markdown engine in order to detect the creation of a macro in the beginning of the document? I suppose this is what has been done to create the GitHub Flavored Markdown, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's anything specifically in Markdown or Jupyter for dong this, but your operating system might be able to help you insert Unicode characters. For example, on my Linux machine I have a [compose key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose_key) configured. If I press <kbd>Compose</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd> <kbd>></kbd> (pressing and releasing each key one at a time) I get "→".

Your operating system might offer a different approach. For example, on Windows you can use [alt codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_code) to enter some special characters. I think <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 2</kbd> followed by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 6</kbd> will insert a → character.

One big benefit of this approach is that you can use it in *all* applications, not just one.

Comment: Thank! Typing  <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad 26</kbd> not only shows the arrow in the rendered document, but also directly in my text editor, which is pretty cool! So this is a big plus, although @KonradRudolph killed my hopes of personal commands / macros ^^'